# Open the output pdf after building using pdflatex in TexnicCenter

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex, texnic-center

I am using the pdflatex compiler in TeXnicCenter, I wanted to be able to change the output file name, without changing the .tex file name, so I used this line at the start of my file:

```
%&pfdlatex -job-name=newfile
```

This method works well, but the compiler doesn't open the pdf automatically anymore, Is there any Command I could use in Viewer instead of the default DDE command to do the job? this is the current command:

```
[DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][FileOpen("%bm.pdf")]
```